# angular client 'server error' on connection to netty-socket.io server

Tags: angular, netty-socketio, ngx-socket-io

I'm trying to connect my Angular app to java socket server base on netty-socket.io but it's not working...

I'm always getting this error on 'connect_error':

```
Error: server error
    at Socket.onPacket (socket.js:393)
    at XHR.Emitter.emit (index.js:145)
    at XHR.onPacket (transport.js:105)
    at callback (polling.js:98)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at XHR.onData (polling.js:102)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (index.js:145)
    at Request.onData (polling-xhr.js:231)
    at Request.onLoad (polling-xhr.js:282)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (polling-xhr.js:186)
```

I'm already try to use **socket.io-client** and **ngx-socket-io**.

Server Side:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(4000);
        config.setOrigin("*");

        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);

        server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
                System.out.println(client.toString());
                client.sendEvent("start", "work";
            }
        });
        server.addEventListener("new-msg", String.class, new DataListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, String data, AckRequest ackSender) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        });

        server.start();
    }
```

Client Side by **socket.io-client**:

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:4000');

    this.socket.on('connection', function () {
      console.log('client connected');
    });

    this.socket.on('connect_error', function(err) {
        console.log("client connect_error: ", err);
    });

    this.socket.on('start', (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    });

    this.socket.emit('new-msg', 'This is a new message');
```

Client Side by **ngx-socket-io**:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SocketIoModule } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot({
      url: 'http://localhost:4000',
      options: {
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Component({
  selector: 'socket-fun-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverIsReady = this.socket.fromEvent<string>('start').subscribe((msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });

  constructor(private socket: Socket) {
    this.socket.on('connect_error', (e: any) => {
      console.log('client connect_error: ', e);
    });

    this.socket.on('connection', () => {
      console.log('client connected');
    });

    this.socket.emit('new-msg', 'This is a new message');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with versioning. Lower your version of the client to 2.x. It worked for me on version 2.0.1 specifically